Timed Out Error while Validation using sf deploy command using jenkins
I am using Jenkins for Salesforce deployment. The stages of are

Authorize to Org -->sf org login jwt --client-id ${SF_CONSUMER_KEY}
--username ${SF_USERNAME} --jwt-key-file ${jwt_key_file}  --instance-url ${SF_INSTANCE_URL}
Validate to the org -->sf project deploy start -o
username -x manifest/package.xml --dry-run
Deploy to the org  --> sf project deploy start -o
username -x manifest/package.xml

The Authorization is getting succeeded, but there is a failure at validation or deployment stage.
Error: failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT

But if we run the pipeline again, the validation is getting passed and deployment is getting succeeded. The session setting for the user is 24 hours, but the timed error says
Can someone help me understand the root cause
